# PHP Function don't executes simple logical task

Tags: php

I got this simple php script. What it does is:

1. user will input the its salary.
2. user will select from the drop down list it's membership type.
3. php script will do simple logic, if the user selects membership type
   as EMPLOYED, it will perform and return the appropriate reply
   *(please refer to my function for better understanding)*
4. if the user selects "Self Employed, Voluntary Member or OFW", it
   will again perform its assigned function

**What my problem is:**

The program is running without errors. The problem is it doesn't display anything. As if nothing is happening. What seems to be the problem?

By the way, i just learned PHP 8 hours ago and i am still in beginner stage trying to experiment with these things. Please help me. Been stuck for couple of hours on this. Please be gentle :)

```
<form method="POST">
Salary: <input id="salarytext" type="text" name="salary" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"><br>
Membership Type:
<select name="membershiptype">
        <option value="employed">Employed</option>
        <option value="SE">Self Employed</option>
        <option value="VM">Voluntary Member</option>
        <option value="OFW">OFW</option>
</select>

<br/>

<input type="submit" />

</form>

<?php

$a = (isset($_POST['salary'])) ? $_POST['salary'] : '';
$b = (isset($_POST['membershiptype'])) ? $_POST['membershiptype'] : '';

function employed () {

        if (empty ($a)) {echo "";}
        elseif ($a<1000) {echo "Your Salary for the Period is $a. <br> You didn't reach the minimum compensation for the period. No SSS Contribution Deduction.";}
        elseif ($a <1249.99) {echo "Your ER is 80.7 and Your EE is 33.3 sevmofw"; }
        elseif ($a <1749.99) {echo "Your ER is 116 and Your EE is 50";}
        elseif ($a <2249.99) {echo "Your ER is 151.3 and Your EE is 66.7";}
        elseif ($a <2749.99) {echo "Your ER is 186.7 and Your EE is 83.3";}
        elseif ($a <3249.99) {echo "Your ER is 222 and Your EE is 100";}
        elseif ($a <3749.99) {echo "Your ER is 257.3 and Your EE is 116.7";}
        elseif ($a <4249.99) {echo "Your ER is 292.7 and Your EE is 133.3";}
        elseif ($a <4749.99) {echo "Your ER is 328 and Your EE is 150";}
        elseif ($a <5249.99) {echo "Your ER is 363.3 and Your EE is 166.7";}
        elseif ($a <5749.99) {echo "Your ER is 398.7 and Your EE is 183.3";}
        elseif ($a <6249.99) {echo "Your ER is 434 and Your EE is 200";}
        elseif ($a <6749.99) {echo "Your ER is 469.3 and Your EE is 216.7";}
        elseif ($a <7249.99) {echo "Your ER is 504.7 and Your EE is 233.3";}
        elseif ($a <7749.99) {echo "Your ER is 540 and Your EE is 250";}
        elseif ($a <8249.99) {echo "Your ER is 575.3 and Your EE is 266.7";}
        elseif ($a <8749.99) {echo "Your ER is 610.7 and Your EE is 283.3";}
        elseif ($a <9249.99) {echo "Your ER is 646 and Your EE is 300";}
        elseif ($a <9749.99) {echo "Your ER is 681.3 and Your EE is 316.7";}
        elseif ($a <10249.99) {echo "Your ER is 716.7 and Your EE is 333.3";}
        elseif ($a <10749.99) {echo "Your ER is 752 and Your EE is 350";}
        elseif ($a <11249.99) {echo "Your ER is 787.3 and Your EE is 366.7";}
        elseif ($a <11749.99) {echo "Your ER is 822.7 and Your EE is 383.3";}
        elseif ($a <12249.99) {echo "Your ER is 858 and Your EE is 400";}
        elseif ($a <12749.99) {echo "Your ER is 893.3 and Your EE is 416.7";}
        elseif ($a <13249.99) {echo "Your ER is 928.7 and Your EE is 433.3";}
        elseif ($a <13749.99) {echo "Your ER is 964 and Your EE is 450";}
        elseif ($a <14249.99) {echo "Your ER is 999.3 and Your EE is 466.7";}
        elseif ($a <14749.99) {echo "Your ER is 1034.7 and Your EE is 483.3";}
        elseif ($a <=30000) {echo "Your ER is 1090 and Your EE is 500";}
        elseif ($a > 30000) {echo "You reached the maximum. Your ER is 1090 and Your EE is 500";}
}

function  sevmofw () {

        if (empty ($a)) {echo "";}
        elseif ($a<1000) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your Salary for the Period is $a. <br> You didn't reach the minimum compensation for the period. No SSS Contribution Deduction.";}
        elseif ($a <1249.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 80.7 and Your EE is 33.3 sevmofw"; }
        elseif ($a <1749.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 116 and Your EE is 50";}
        elseif ($a <2249.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 151.3 and Your EE is 66.7";}
        elseif ($a <2749.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 186.7 and Your EE is 83.3";}
        elseif ($a <3249.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 222 and Your EE is 100";}
        elseif ($a <3749.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 257.3 and Your EE is 116.7";}
        elseif ($a <4249.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 292.7 and Your EE is 133.3";}
        elseif ($a <4749.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 328 and Your EE is 150";}
        elseif ($a <5249.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 363.3 and Your EE is 166.7";}
        elseif ($a <5749.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 398.7 and Your EE is 183.3";}
        elseif ($a <6249.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 434 and Your EE is 200";}
        elseif ($a <6749.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 469.3 and Your EE is 216.7";}
        elseif ($a <7249.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 504.7 and Your EE is 233.3";}
        elseif ($a <7749.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 540 and Your EE is 250";}
        elseif ($a <8249.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 575.3 and Your EE is 266.7";}
        elseif ($a <8749.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 610.7 and Your EE is 283.3";}
        elseif ($a <9249.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 646 and Your EE is 300";}
        elseif ($a <9749.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 681.3 and Your EE is 316.7";}
        elseif ($a <10249.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 716.7 and Your EE is 333.3";}
        elseif ($a <10749.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 752 and Your EE is 350";}
        elseif ($a <11249.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 787.3 and Your EE is 366.7";}
        elseif ($a <11749.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 822.7 and Your EE is 383.3";}
        elseif ($a <12249.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 858 and Your EE is 400";}
        elseif ($a <12749.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 893.3 and Your EE is 416.7";}
        elseif ($a <13249.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 928.7 and Your EE is 433.3";}
        elseif ($a <13749.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 964 and Your EE is 450";}
        elseif ($a <14249.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 999.3 and Your EE is 466.7";}
        elseif ($a <14749.99) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 1034.7 and Your EE is 483.3";}
        elseif ($a <30000) {echo "NOT EMPLOYED. Your ER is 1090 and Your EE is 500";}
        elseif ($a > 30000) {echo "You reached the maximum. Your ER is 1090 and Your EE is 500";}
}




if ( $_POST['membershiptype'] == 'employed' ){employed();
} elseif ( $_POST['membershiptype'] == 'SE' ){sevmofw();
} elseif ( $_POST['membershiptype'] == 'VM' ){sevmofw();
} elseif ( $_POST['membershiptype'] == 'OFW' ){sevmofw();
}


?>
```

Comment: And you see nothing at all? What happens when you *View Source*?

Comment: `$a` is not in the function's scope. Feed it to the function as a parameter.

Comment: need to learn about variable scope - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php Look at the second box/example, as it specifically addresses your issue.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, i can see the form, drop down list and the submit button. but it doesnt executes the function.. nothing is happening.

Comment: @Wrikken, Im sorry, can't understand. Still a newbie. English please. :)

Comment: @Wrikken is saying to add a function parameter - `function employed($a) {...}`. And then when you call the function add the variable - `if ( $_POST['membershiptype'] == 'employed' ){employed($a);}`

Comment: i see. I'll try these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$a` and `$b` are out of scope. You need to **pass them as arguments to the function**.

```
/* SNIP */
function employed($a, $b) { //Note that the function now accepts two parameters. These will be available in the function.

/* SNIP */
function sevmofw($a, $b) { //Same idea.

/* SNIP */
if ($_POST['membershiptype'] == 'employed') {
    employed($a, $b); //Pass the variables into the function from the outside.
}
elseif ($_POST['membershiptype'] == 'SE') {
    sevmofw($a, $b);
}
elseif ($_POST['membershiptype'] == 'VM') {
    sevmofw($a, $b);
}
elseif ($_POST['membershiptype'] == 'OFW') {
    sevmofw($a, $b);
}
```

Comment: I got this error:

SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
Undefined index: membershiptype in C:\wamp\www\php_sandbox\switch.php on line 120, 123, 126 & 129

Comment: actually, it's working already. The problem is when I open the php, it will display the errors. but when i start to input some figures it returns the correct output.

Comment: @KareenLagasca I think you want to replace all of the `$_POST['membershiptype']` in the if/elseif blocks with `$b`, as you are setting it earlier as `$b = (isset($_POST['membershiptype'])) ? $_POST['membershiptype'] : '';`. Then on page load it will not give you the `Undefined index` warning as you checked it before with `isset()`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are more problems with your code, including, mixing business and presentation logic and responsibilities as well...

But, to be specific to the question,

First of all, `switch` should be used instead of bunch of `if/elseif`

Second,

your function `employed()` has no clue on what `$a` is. You'd supply it as an argument.

```
function employed($a){

   switch(true){

      case $a < 100:

        echo "Your Salary for the Period is $a. <br> You didn't reach the minimum compensation for the period. No SSS Contribution Deduction."   

      break;

      case $a < 1249.99:
         echo "Your ER is 80.7 and Your EE is 33.3 sevmofw";
      break;

      ......
   }
}
```

That will work as expected.